# AMD RAID 5 not booting after Windows Server 2012 updates

Tags: windows, boot, bios, raid

I've recently been working to reconfigure my home server. I decided to setup a RAID 5 for my operating system and virtual machines using my Asus M5A97 R2.0 built in AMD RAID. I was able to setup the RAID 5 without an issue, I even managed to get Windows Server 2012 installed and partially configured. After installing some roles, the system rebooted right back into the OS without an issue. However; after letting it go over night installing Windows updates, I rebooted it the next morning and now BIOS just spits out a 'No bookable disk' error although the array still shows functional.

Here are my [current BIOS settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FzcIK.jpg).

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FzcIK.jpg]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FzcIK.jpg]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FzcIK.jpg]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FzcIK.jpg]

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: After booting into a Windows 10 flash drive and loading the AMD RAID driver, I can see the ~4TB RAID 5 array but it is showing as uninitialized and unallocated. The issue seems to be very similar to the ones mentioned in [this thread](https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fc524630-51d3-4518-ba75-b7fe424f2c87/windows-home-server-2011-updates-broke-my-raid-5?forum=whs2011).